# type object is not subscriptable BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
}
url = 'http://www.sahibinden.com/coklu-calisma-masasi'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.content, "html.parser")


Liste = list["bla","bla"]



for i in range(10):
    liste[i] = soup.find("a", {"class":"classifiedTitle"})


print(Liste)
```

I run this code and i get this error https://prnt.sc/qvifx8
What can i do for this error

Comment: `Liste = list["bla","bla"]` should be just `Liste = ["bla","bla"]`. Lower down, `liste` does not agree with the name you used before. Python is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```py
list["bla","bla"]
```

Is not a valid list declaration. You have used square brackets, which in Python are the notation for subscripting. Hence your error: `list` is a type, and is not subscriptable.

Try this instead

```py
list("bla","bla")
```

Or the more standard list declaration:

```py
["bla","bla"]
```

---

On another note, when you give an object a generic name in python, try to come up with something descriptive for the name like `word_list` rather than a "near miss" name like `liste`. Or if it really is a plain-old list that doesn't deserve any specification, then its typical to use a name like `l`. But whatever you choose, [variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) should be `lower_case`

Comment: @C.Aydın in that screenshot you've used parentheses `(  )` alone which create a tuple, not a list. If you use `list()` or `[ ]` it will create a list, see my final 2 examples in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have misunderstood how lists work. Rather than this:

```
Liste = list["bla","bla"]
```

You should define it like this:

```
Liste = ["bla","bla"]
```

However, lower down you rewrite the elements. So assuming you only want to take the first 10 elements (based on your `for i in range(10)`) which follow the conditions `("a", {"class":"classifiedTitle"})` you should do this:

```
Liste = soup.find_all("a", {"class":"classifiedTitle"})[:10]
```

Comment: @C.Aydın `print(urunler[9].text)`

Comment: And last question :) I want to get only the products that say "SNR" in the product list in the list of 20 items I have drawn.

Comment: In your function make `urunler = [x for x in soup.find_all("a", {"class":"classifiedTitle"}) if "SNR" in x.text]`

Comment: def urunKontroll():
 for i in range(6):
  url = Kategoriler[i]
  r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  soup = bs(r.content, "html.parser")
  for x in range(20):
   urunler = [x for x in soup.find_all("a", {"class":"classifiedTitle"}) if "SNR" in x.text]
   print("Kategori ", i+1 , " --- ", urunler[x].text)

Comment: Move `urunler = [x for x in soup.find_all("a", {"class":"classifiedTitle"}) if "SNR" in x.text]` outside of the for-loop and to just below `soup = ...`. Then change `for x in range(20)` to `for x in range(len(urunler))`. Because we're only looking at elements with "SNR" in their text, there are no longer 20 elements in the list.